# Click event not triggering in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React, I have 3 components:

- `App`, contains `UserList`
- `UserList`, contains a list of cards
- `UserCard`, the content of the previous component

Here's my `UserList` code:

```
 state = {
    users: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Chris', age: 20 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Max', age: 1 },
      { id: 3, name: 'Jean', age: 23 },
      { id: 4, name: 'Luc', age: 30 }
    ]
  }

  userList = this.state.users.map(user => {
    return (
    <div key={user.id} className="column">
      <UserCard name={user.name} age={user.age} onClick={this.userClickHandler} />
    </div>);
  });

  userClickHandler = () => {
    console.log('clicked !');
  };

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="columns">
      {this.userList}
    </div>);
  }
```

For some odd reason, my `userClickHandler` does not get triggered when a `UserCard` is clicked.

Note that I have tried the following:

Changing `onClick={this.userClickHandler}` to `onClick= () => {this.userClickHandler}` and that it works when I move the code of my `userList` in the render method without assigning it to a variable like so:

```
<div className="columns">     
  { this.state.users.map(user => {
    return (
    <div key={user.id} className="column" onClick={this.userClickHandler}>
      <UserCard name={user.name} age={user.age} />
    </div>);
  }) }
</div>);
```

What's the apparent problem?

Comment: tried `this.userClickHandler()` ?

Comment: @Jeffin that should not work.

Comment: Could you please show more of you userList code?

Comment: please show us the UserCard code

Comment: I think you called `{this.userList}` while this is mean a function but base on your code you assigned to a var, let or const. Just call `userList`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the function to the scope here..Sorry about my previous answer.  I didn't analyse it properly

```
<div key={user.id} className="column" onClick={this.userClickHandler.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: I moved the function before my `userList` and removed the parenthesis and it worked. Having the parenthesis triggers the function x times (x being the number of users)

Comment: @Christopher Did you bind that function?

Comment: No need to bind an arrow function, right?

Comment: yes without arrow function, the function should be binded to the scope either in constructor or while creating instance

Comment: no, actually you use bind if you want to to use the setState() function. that's not the case tho.

Comment: Since the function was used inside map.  The scope changes for every iteration.  Thats y.  Otherwise no need for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I'd store something like this in a variable in the render section like this. Let me know if this helps. :

```
      render() {

      let userList = this.state.users.map(user => {
        return (
        <div key={user.id} className="column">
          <UserCard name={user.name} age={user.age} onClick={this.userClickHandler} />
        </div>);
      });
        return (
        <div className="columns">
          {userList}
        </div>);
      }
```

Also, in the constructor of userList, bind the click handler:

```
constructor(){
  this.userClickHandler = this.userClickHandler.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could likely be that you've discovered function hoisting.
Arrow functions are not hoisted.

You are only able to make it invoke it after you've declared it.

A normal function using a function keyword can be invoked at a line number before it is declared.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting